# Building a simple computer to computer messenger using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a script that sends a message to another IP. Using telnet seems like the only protocol that would work. I'm using this as a learning experience for Bash and I've already done some reading on how it could work.

I've understood that I should use a program named Expect to communicate but, again, seeing as I'm new it seems like a whole lot.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to come about approaching this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/). You can send packets over TCP/IP, and listen to ports. You don't need any more :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)
I took a look at the source and there's alot of files (not that it's a bad thing). I guess what I wanted to do couldn't be done in a couple flat files like I thought. I'll definitely check this out and play around with it a little.

Comment: Hey, your installation might already have netcat or nc installed. Check your system, and if not: most package managers have a version too. What linux distro are you on? Finally, installing from source is not that hard...

Comment: Nono I'm not saying installing for source is hard or anything :) I do it most of the time. I just thought this could be accomplished more simply but that's because I don't know much about Bash. I'm currently running the latest OpenSuse

Comment: Oh but you probably could do it simpler. Sending a message can be done with telnet, but to receive it you'd indeed need some kind of daemon to receive the message. netcat is a simple and common building block :)